# Unhandled exception Class.forname("com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver") in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sql, google-app-engine, jdbc

I have a project in Android Studio that has a **Google Cloud Endpoints** module. I'm trying to connect my endpoints module to an instance of **Google Cloud SQL** that I have in that same project.

In the IDE I see the following error:

```
Unhandled exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

My gradle build shows:

```
Error:(82, 26) error: unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown 
Error:(87, 26) error: unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

I have enabled the J connector in the `appengine-web.xml`

[image]

I'm not sure what I need to do to connect to my SQL db to my Google App Engine. It seems to be more complicated than I thought.

My code:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getLesson")
public Lesson getLesson(@Named("id") Long id) {

    Lesson l = new Lesson();

    l.setLessonId(345);
    l.setLessonColour("Blue");
    l.setLessonImage("itshappening.gif");



    String url = null;
    if (SystemProperty.environment.value() ==
            SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
        // Connecting from App Engine.
        // Load the class that provides the "jdbc:google:mysql://"
        // prefix.
        Class.forName("com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver");
        url =
                "jdbc:google:mysql://app:instance?user=root";
    } else {
        // Connecting from an external network.
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        url = "jdbc:mysql://000.000.000.000:3306?user=root";
    }

    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        l.setLessonDescription(e.getStackTrace().toString());
    }

    try {
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(
                "SELECT 1 + 56");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    logger.info("Calling getLesson method");

    return l;
}
```

Any help, comments or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`Class.forName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) will throw a [`ClassNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) when the given class cannot be located.

Since `ClassNotFoundException` is a [checked exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Checked_exceptions), you actually have to deal with the possibility that one might occur. You can do this either by passing it on to the calling method. To do this, you have to add it to your method's signature:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getLesson")
public Lesson getLesson(@Named("id") Long id) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    // ...
```

Then the method that called the current method has to deal with it.

Alternatively, you can also deal with it directly inside your current method, using a [try/catch block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html):

```
try {
    // ...

    Class.forName("com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver");

    // ...
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this example, it will simply print the stack trace of the exception to `System.err`. You can change that error handling to whatever you want.

Comment: Sigh. Not as complicated as I thought ... Thanks for your insight / help. I should have seen this.

Answer (score 1):

`ClassNotFoundException` is a checked exception, so you must either catch it or throw it, as the error says.

To follow your current scheme of exception handling:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    l.setLessonDescription(e.getStackTrace().toString());
}
```